# Javascript setInterval function not defined

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this code I seem to be geting an error that timer is not defined

```
var counter = setInterval("timer()",1000);

            function timer(){
                count = count-1;
                if(count <=0){
                    clearInterval(counter);
                    return;
                }
                document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count + " sec";
            }
```

Comment: You need to pass the function, not a string, as first param.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Don't pass a string to `setInterval`.

Your function is a local variable, which doesn't exist when `setTimeout` eval's the string in the global scope.

Instead, pass the function itself to `setInterval`:

```
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

Comment: may be worth noting that if he's only calling `timer` from this one place then it can just become an anonymous passed to `setTimeout`.

Comment: ok the function now works only wierd thing is that firefox web development addon seems to still think that timer is not defined and gives the error every time the function runs.Do you know why that happens?